# Почему не подключается к домену? Windows

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server, hyper-v

У меня Windows Server 2019 установлен на hyper-v.В нем я настроил Active Directory. При подключении к домену из основной операционки появляется окно авторизации, но после него вылетает ошибка. В чем может быть проблема? Имя пользователя и пароль указываются стандартного пользователя который создается автоматически при настройке Active Directory.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: y]

Comment: Нет доступа к доменному контроллеру. Скорее всего, сетевая проблема.